# Accessing clipboard on Travis-CI

Tags: python, pytest, travis-ci, pyperclip, xclip

I am trying to run an (integration?) test on my [application](https://github.com/josephjcontreras/searchlists/tree/travis), to verify that it actually copies the expected string to the clipboard with `pyperclip`.

This part is working on my development machine (Windows 10); but fails on travis-ci, where I get the following in my travis job log.

```
self = <pyperclip.init_no_clipboard.<locals>.ClipboardUnavailable object at 0x7ff0cd743588>
args = ('7 809823 102890 string 291',), kwargs = {}
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>       raise PyperclipException(EXCEPT_MSG)
E       pyperclip.PyperclipException: 
E           Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
E           For more information, please visit https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#not-implemented-error
../../../virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py:301: PyperclipException
```

According the to the [pyperclip documentation](https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#not-implemented-error), this occurs on Linux when there is no copy/paste mechanism. The solution is to install one of the following (quoting `pyperclip` docs):

- `sudo apt-get install xsel` to install the xsel utility.
- `sudo apt-get install xclip` to install the xclip utility.
- `pip install gtk` to install the gtk Python module.
- `pip install PyQt4` to install the PyQt4 Python module.

So in my `.travis.yml` file, I have

```
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get install xclip
```

I've also tried `xsel`, with the same results.

Since the system on travis is Ubuntu 16.04.6, I tried adding `sudo apt-get install python3-pyperclip` to the `before_install` key, with the same result.

I was not able to install either `gtk` or `PyQt4` by adding them to the `install` key in `.travis.yml`.

```
install:
  - pip install -r requirements_dev.txt
  - pip install PyQt4
  # or
  - pip install gtk
```

As these both result in the following error:

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gtk (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gtk
The command "pip install gtk" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

By this point, my `before_install` looks like this:

```
  - sudo apt-get install xclip
  - sudo apt-get install xsel
  - sudo apt-get install python3-pyperclip
  - sudo apt-get install gtk2.0
```

This seems like overkill (and still does not work); but I am currently out of ideas on how to make that test pass. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you mock the pyperclip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xclip` requires an X server to be running, while Travis machines run in headless mode. You need to run the command in a virtual framebuffer; install `xvfb` in addition to `xclip` and use `xvfb-run pytest` instead of `pytest`. Full config example:

```yml
language: python
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - xclip
    - xvfb
python:
  - "3.7"

# setup installation
install:
  - pip install -r requirements_dev.txt

script: xvfb-run pytest
```

Here's an example [build on Travis](https://travis-ci.org/hoefling/searchlists/builds/579379427). Notice that I used `addons` to declare dependencies that should be installed with APT; your solution with installing them explicitly in a `before_install` section is perfectly valid too, just a matter of taste.

Comment: This worked. Thanks for the explanation. I also liked the addons format better; thanks for the tip.

Comment: Glad I could help!